# Trying to use FFMPEG in C and Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, ffmpeg, linker-errors

I have been trying to use FFMPEG in gcc under Ubuntu. I've done the linking stuff required in order to make my code compile but i get the following errors:

```
tutorial01.c:(.text+0x37d): undefined reference to `avcodec_decode_video'
tutorial01.c:(.text+0x3c5): undefined reference to `img_convert'
```

The source I use is the one from the following tutorial http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.c

(original link: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html)

I know that the source of the turotorial is quite old. So does anyone know of any new  functions that replace the ones mentioned in the error messages??

ALso are there any updated documenation oin tutorial form that i could possibly use?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: See the [updated source code version](https://github.com/chelyaev/ffmpeg-tutorial) of that guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing to link the library `libavcodec`.

Add the linker option `-lavcodec` and optionally provide the library's path using the open `-L`<sup>*1</sup>.

---

<sup>*1: Please note that `-L` needs to proceed `-l`. So if `libmyname.a/.so` resides in `/some/path/` use: `-L/some/path/ -lmyname`</sup>

Comment: @obelix: If you this answer helped you might like to upvote it.